# VBA Lookup function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in sheet1 of a workbook like this:

```
section  |  Class  
11       |  2  
11       |  2  
12       |  3  
12       |  3  
12       |  3  
13       |  4
```

On sheet 2 I have something like this:

```
section  |  Class  
11       |    
11       |   
11       |  
11       |  
11       |  
11       |   
12       |    
12       |    
12       |  
12       |  
12       |    
13       |
```

I want to use the lookup function in sheet2 to get the value for Class from sheet1 and this is the macro that is generated for the first cell only:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1],Sheet1!RC:R[4]C)"
```

My actual formula is:

```
=LOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:A6,Sheet1!B2:B6)
```

I would want it to be like:

```
=LOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:A6,Sheet1!$B$2:B6)
```

but this not allowed.
Could anybody help me fill in the Class column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
Sub GetClasses()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")
lr1 = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wsDest.Range("B2:B" & lr2).Formula = "=LOOKUP(A2,'" & wsSource.Name & "'!$A$2:$A$" & lr1 & ",'" & wsSource.Name & "'!$B$2:$B$" & lr1 & ")"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 2):

R1C1 reference style is a bit strange at first, but you should try to understand it if you are going to do VBA.

Square brackets denote relative reference, no brackets mean absolute reference:

`R1C4` = Row 1, Column 4 = `$D$1`
`R[1]C[-2]` = Relative to where the formula is, 1 Row down and 2 Columns to the left.
`[0]` becomes nothing, so `R[0]C[1]` would actually become `RC[1]`, meaning same row, one column to the right.

So in your case, the formula should look like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=LOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!R2C1:R[4]C[-1],Sheet1!R2C2:R[4]C)"
```

You can have Excel display formulas like this, it might help understand how this formula type works. In File/Options/Formulas, tick "R1C1 Reference Style".

Alternatively you can use `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1` as @sktneer did. It is easier at first, though you will find it is more limited in its uses in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the quick intro to R1C1. Your first two points made way more sense than many of the websites I've gone through. Will be learning more about it for sure. It is relatively elegant.